# GitHub desktop repository changing repo names automatically

Tags: html, github, github-pages, github-desktop

I’m having a continuous problem with my GitHub desktop (windows 10). I have a repo (let’s call it repo A) that I have made a website by hand on. Uploading all the files and changes. I also have another repo (repo B) which I am trying to use with GitHub pages to host my site temporarily. Now when I try to clone repo B (currently empty) onto my desktop it instantly changes the name of repo B to the name of repo A and syncing the files between them, hence rendering it useless for GitHub pages as repo B must be named “username.github.io” to host. Why is this happening and how do I fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like in [desktop/desktop issue 5055](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5055#issuecomment-402538278), try instead to:

- clone repo B through command line
- use  File | Add Local Repository to import repoB into GitHub Desktop

See if the issue persists then.

Comment: Ah thanks, I’m in class at the moment but I will check that solution tonight